# Can't access the apis from inside the monogdb connect function in vercel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vercel

I am working on an express server, and using mongodb as database. The server is working on local. I have deployed the server to vercel with git repository. Heres the deployed server, https://annoor-server.vercel.app/ when i hit the url it serves the response form the "/" api, but when i hit https://annoor-server.vercel.app/get-product (which api is inside the mongodb connect function) it says Cannot GET /get-product.

> Here the repository https://github.com/shahadat2772/annoor-server

> **vercel.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

> **index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const {
  MongoClient,
  ServerApiVersion,
  TopologyDescriptionChangedEvent,
  ObjectId,
} = require("mongodb");
const PORT = 5000 || process.env.PORT;
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const verify = require("jsonwebtoken/verify");
const multer = require("multer");

// All Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const path = require("path");
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets")));

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.trnyuya.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

// Img upload middleware
const imageFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // filter image file
  //check file type is image
  if (file.mimetype.includes("image/png")) {
    // if image file
    cb(null, true);
  } else if (file.mimetype.includes("image/jpeg")) {
    // if image file
    cb(null, true);
  } else if (file.mimetype.includes("image/jpg")) {
    // if image file
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Please upload only jpg, png or jpeg image.", false);
  }
};

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // multer storage
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./assets" + "/"); // upload file to backend/
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    // rename file
    const ext = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
    const filename = Date.now() + "." + ext;
    req.filename = filename;
    cb(null, filename);
  },
});
var uploadFile = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFilter });

// TO VERIFY TOKEN
function verifyJWT(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers?.authorization;
  if (!authHeader) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "unauthorized", success: false });
  }
  const accessToken = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET_TOKEN, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res
        .status(403)
        .send({ message: "forbidden access", success: false });
    }
    if (decoded.uid !== req.headers.uid) {
      return res
        .status(403)
        .send({ message: "forbidden access", success: false });
    }
    req.decoded = decoded;
    next();
  });
}

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello there!");
});

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connecting with mongodb
    await client.connect();

    // Collections
    const userCollection = client
      .db("annoor-business")
      .collection("users-collection");

    const productCollection = client
      .db("annoor-business")
      .collection("product-collection");

    app.get("/get-product", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        // const category = req.headers?.category;
        // const filter = { category: category };
        const result = await productCollection.find({}).toArray();
        res.status(200).send({
          data: result,
          success: true,
          message: "Got products data.",
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Internal server error.",
          success: false,
        });
      }
    });

    // app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    //   res.send("Hello there!");
    // });

    // Verify admin
    async function verifyAdmin(req, res, next) {
      const uid = req?.decoded?.uid;
      const filter = { uid };
      const user = await userCollection.findOne(filter);
      const role = user?.role;
      if (role === "admin") {
        next();
      } else {
        return res
          .status(403)
          .send({ message: "forbidden access", success: false });
      }
    }

    // Get token/user creation
    app.put("/token", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const userInfo = req.body;
        const doc = {
          $set: userInfo,
        };
        const uid = userInfo.uid;
        const option = {
          upsert: true,
        };
        const result = await userCollection.updateOne({ uid }, doc, option);
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ uid }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_TOKEN, {
          expiresIn: "1d",
        });
        res
          .status(200)
          .send({ data: accessToken, success: true, message: "Got token" });
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({ message: "Internal server error.", success: false });
      }
    });

    // Get user info
    app.get("/user", verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const uid = req.headers.uid;
        const filter = { uid };
        const user = await userCollection.findOne(filter);
        res
          .status(200)
          .send({ data: user, success: true, message: "Got user info" });
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({ success: false, message: "Internal server error." });
      }
    });

    // Update user profile
    app.post("/update-user-info", verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const uid = req.headers.uid;
        const updatedInfo = req.body;
        const filter = { uid };
        const option = {
          upsert: true,
        };
        const doc = {
          $set: updatedInfo,
        };
        const result = await userCollection.updateOne(filter, doc, option);
        res.status(200).send({ message: "Profile updated.", success: true });
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({ message: "Internal server error.", success: false });
      }
    });

    // Get products by category
    app.get("/product", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const category = req.headers?.category;
        const filter = { category: category };
        const result = await productCollection.find(filter).toArray();
        res.status(200).send({
          data: result,
          success: true,
          message: "Got products data.",
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Internal server error.",
          success: false,
        });
      }
    });

    // Admin Routes

    // Add Product
    app.post(
      "/product",
      verifyJWT,
      verifyAdmin,
      uploadFile.single("image"),
      async (req, res) => {
        try {
          let path = "http://localhost:5000/assets/" + req.filename;
          const product = req.body;

          const productInfo = {
            name: product.name,
            category: product.category,
            subtext: product.subtext,
            stock: product.stock,
            description: product.description,
            price: product.price,
            image: path,
          };
          const result = await productCollection.insertOne(productInfo);
          res.status(200).send({ message: "Product added.", success: true });
        } catch (error) {
          res
            .status(500)
            .send({ path, message: "Internal server error.", success: false });
        }
      }
    );

    // Edit Product
    app.post(
      "/edit-product",
      verifyJWT,
      verifyAdmin,
      uploadFile.single("image"),
      async (req, res) => {
        try {
          const filter = { _id: ObjectId(req.headers._id) };
          const product = req.body;
          let productInfo = {
            name: product.name,
            category: product.category,
            subtext: product.subtext,
            stock: product.stock,
            description: product.description,
            price: product.price,
          };

          if (req?.filename) {
            let path = "http://localhost:5000/assets/" + req.filename;
            productInfo = { ...productInfo, image: path };
          }

          const doc = {
            $set: productInfo,
          };

          const result = await productCollection.updateOne(filter, doc);
          res
            .status(200)
            .send({ message: "Updated the product.", success: true });
        } catch (error) {
          res
            .status(500)
            .send({ message: "Internal server error.", success: false });
        }
      }
    );

    // Get all products / search products
    app.get("/all-products", verifyJWT, verifyAdmin, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const page = parseInt(req?.query?.page) - 1;
        const search = req?.query?.search;
        let products;
        let productCount;

        if (search !== "") {
          const query = { $text: { $search: search } };
          productCount = await productCollection.countDocuments(query);
          products = await productCollection
            .find(query)
            .skip(page * 15)
            .limit(15)
            .toArray();
        } else {
          productCount = await productCollection.estimatedDocumentCount();
          products = await productCollection
            .find({})
            .sort({ $natural: -1 })
            .skip(page * 15)
            .limit(15)
            .toArray();
        }

        res.status(200).send({
          success: true,
          message: "Got all products",
          data: products,
          productCount: productCount,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
          success: false,
          message: "Internal server error.",
        });
      }
    });

    // Delete a product
    app.delete("/delete-product", verifyJWT, verifyAdmin, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const filter = { _id: ObjectId(req.headers._id) };
        const result = await productCollection.deleteOne(filter);
        res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: "Product deleted." });
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({ success: false, message: "Internal server error." });
      }
    });

    // Get product by id
    app.get("/single-product", verifyJWT, verifyAdmin, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const filter = { _id: ObjectId(req.headers._id) };
        const result = await productCollection.findOne(filter);
        res
          .status(200)
          .send({ success: true, message: "Got single product", data: result });
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({ success: false, message: "Internal server error." });
      }
    });
  } finally {
    // await client.close();
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Responding to port", PORT);
});

// Export the Express API
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of run() function on your app., but if you get the app.get(/get-products) out of run(), the app might work

Comment: @FarhadFaraji Thanks, I am trying to connect with monogdb with the run function, and kept the apis and collections that function, can i get a better or right way to connect with monogdb? so that it works with vercel.